# Facebook ChatHead Like Fling Animation Android

Tags: android

So I am working on a floating view. I have managed to create the complete view, it looks similar to a Facebook chathead.

**What I want to do:**
I want to add in that fling gesture to my view. For example: I want my view to be in either the right or left edge of the screen, so a user should be able to fling it to either edge of the screen like we can in fb messenger chat head as well.

Could someone please guide me how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the motion tracking features from Android SDK.
Check this out: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html

It's probably the VelocityTracker API that you need.